# file input stream odd behaviour

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have the following simple code that reads from a file in the current directory into a byte array and the prints the contents of the array (which is the contents of the file, ASCII printable characters from ASCII 32 to ASCII 126):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class Input {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try {
      fis=new FileInputStream("file.txt");
      int available=fis.available();
      byte[] read=new byte[available];
      int bytesRead;
      int offset=0;
      while(offset<read.length) {
        bytesRead=fis.read(read,offset,read.length-offset);
        if (bytesRead==-1) break;
        offset+=bytesRead;
      }
      System.out.println(read.length);
      for (byte b:read) {
        int i=b & 0xFF;
        System.out.write(i);
        System.out.write('\t');
      }
    }
    finally {
      if (fis != null)
        try {
          fis.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

}
```

but when it run it only prints 64 characters to the standard output (even if the debug string prints 96 bytes in the array, as it should be..)
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the content of `file.txt` ? Some characters inside the file may not be printable. What did you really expect ? Note that reading a file like this is not reasonable, you are creating an array of size the size of the file (which may be huge). What did you expect with `b&0xFF` ?

Comment: the contents of the file are in the question

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Apparently every ASCII character from value 32 through 126. Although that are 95 characters and not 96...

Comment: @Siguza yes,I included delete,which is 127

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem, although I don't get 64 characters printed, but just a single line which is cut off where my command line window ends. Replacing `write` with `print` and casting `i` to `char` does not help either, but removing the tabs does...

Comment: Hi Luca, can you paste the files.txt here.. also the sample output that you are getting rite now?

Comment: @Siguza - I repro'd as well, by setting available to various numbers. I think it may be a write-buffer-flush issue - I added a println after the for(byte b:read) loop, and started getting output.

Comment: It seems to work correctly as `java Input | more` gives the right result. Something happens on the terminal that I can't actually understand.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Java issue, but more like a shell issue with tabs. [This Java program](https://ideone.com/QTfrfW) works on Ideone, but has the same problem when run from my shell. The exact same thing happens when running `php -r 'for($i=32;$i<128;++$i){echo chr($i)."\t";}'`. Yet, both commands work when piped to `less` (or `more`), but not `cat`, `tee`, `head` or `tail`. The result is also the same when run from `bash`, `sh`, `csh`, `ksh` and `zsh`. The output can also be captured correctly using `myvar=$(...)`, but `echo "$myvar"` will produce the same problem again.

Comment: It seems to be that System.out is a buffered OutputStream,so its write method doesn't just write to the standard output,but buffers writes,so it needs flushing. If I add a `System.out.flush();`  after the for-each everything is printed. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're need to `flush()` the `System.out`, as it will only flush on `\n` if `autoFlush` is set (default). See the documentation [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and the option .